# Reference SSL Keystore from Java Callout

Tags: apigee

Is it possible to reference an uploaded SSL Certificate within a Java Callout in Apigee? I have successfully uploaded a Client-SSL certificate using the following guide: http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/client-ssl-backend-servers

I am able to reference the SSL certificate using the following from a target proxy and Service Callout but how do you reference the SSL certificate from a Java Callout?

```
  <HTTPTargetConnection>
    <SSLInfo>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ClientAuthEnabled>true</ClientAuthEnabled>
      <KeyStore>myKeystore</KeyStore>
      <KeyAlias>myKey</KeyAlias>
      <TrustStore>myTruststore</TrustStore>
    </SSLInfo>
    <URL>https://myservice.com</URL>
  </HTTPTargetConnection>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you should not. There is a security restriction in Apigee that does not allow you to access com.apigee.* packages from javacallout.